# Multiply by number all ellements of an array with forEach in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have an array of numbers:

```
var array = [ 23, 67, 120, 170, 200, 212, 350 ];
```

and I want to scale down by 20% each of the element of the array.

I used `array.forEach(function(item) {item * 0.8;});`, but it did nothing. I tried also `var scaledArray = array.forEach(function(item) {item * 0.8;});`, but the result was undefined.

Comment: Have you checked out underscore.js?  You can map the array elements.

Comment: `.forEach(function() { <code> })` is basically equivalent to `for(...) { <code> }`. You are multiplying two numbers but you are not doing anything with the result. It doesn't magically do something for you.

Comment: @dustmouse As seen in the answers, [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is a fairly widely available function in native javascript now without using libraries.  The linked page also has a polyfill for browsers that don't support it natively.

Comment: @James Thorpe.  Some older browsers like IE 8 and below don't support the native array map function.  Why not use a well documented and relatively standard library like underscore.js that can handle the browser compatibility/implementation details as well as offer tons of other functionality?

Comment: @dustmouse that's what the polyfill does. It fills in implementations for browsers that lack them.

Comment: Okay, so you can add the polyfill to your script, or you can use a library that already handles it as well as a bunch of additional functionality.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) invokes the provided function against each element in the array; it does not return a new array with modified values (that come from calling the provided function against each element). What you want to use is [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
array = array.map(function(element) {
    return element * 0.8;
});
```

This will map every element of the array according to the mapping function that you have provided, and return a new array that consists of those mapped values.

If you want to keep the original array around, you can simply assign the result of `map` to a different variable:

```
var scaledArray = array.map(function(element) {
    return element * 0.8;
});
```

You *could* do both of these with `forEach` like:

```
array.forEach(function(element, index, _array) {
    _array[index] = element * 0.8;
});
```

and:

```
var scaledArray = [];
array.forEach(function(element, index) {
    scaledArray[index] = element * 0.8;
});
```

But I'm sure you'll agree that the `map` version is much more elegant and idiomatic.

Comment: Please appreciate that the author explained the difference not only provide solution. +1

Comment: The third argument to foreach is the array itself so you can use that instead of referencing it from the outside.

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` instead of `forEach`:

```
var arr = array.map(function(item) {return item * 0.8;})
```

The [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method creates a new array with the results of calling a
provided function on every element in this array, `forEach` doesn't create a new array.

Comment: I agree with it and it would be better the following `array.map(item => item * 0.8)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it using `forEach`:

```js
var array = [ 23, 67, 120, 170, 200, 212, 350 ]

array.forEach(function(val, idx) {
  array[idx]= val * 0.8;
});

alert(array.join('\r'));
```

[`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is generally the more straight-forward solution, but it may actually be slower than [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for something like this, because `forEach` can modify the array in-place:

http://jsperf.com/foreach-v-map

Answer (score 0):

**You could use `map`** which is straight-forward **but if you want to work with `forEach`**, be aware:

- `.forEach(function() { <code> })` is equivalent to `(...) { <code> }.`.

**You are multiplying numbers but not doing anything with those numbers**. You could change the actual array you're working on but should assign that operation to the array. (I've also added `.toFixed(2)` to round the result to 2 decimal places and as the result is a `string`, added Number() to the whole result.

```
let array = [ 23, 67, 120, 170, 200, 212, 350 ];
array.forEach ( function(x,i) {
array[i] = (x * .8).toFixed(2);
console.log(array); 
});
```